# Optimize parsing more and more.... in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have below C# code for parsing ... Do you think this is most optimize or I should use generic method or optimization required in these function itself?

```
public static bool GetDBBool(object value)
{
    var result = false;

    if (value != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) == false)
        bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);

    return result;
}

public static int GetDBInt(object value)
{
    var result = -999;

    if (value != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) == false)
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);

    return result;
}

public static double GetDBDouble(object value)
{
    var result = -999.00;

    if (value != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) == false)
        double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);

    return result;
}

public static DateTime GetDBDate(object value)
{
    var result = DateTime.Now;

    if (value != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) == false)
        DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);

    return result;
}

public static DateTime? GetDBNullableDate(object value)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (value != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) == false)
        return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date) ? date : (DateTime?)null;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: If you are junior developer and want to learn code please use http://www.learncs.org/ to understand what this code does.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear what this does, it's just unclear what you're asking. Like @psubsee says, go to CodeReview if you want a code review.

Comment: You could certainly use generics and reduce the amount of code you have - whether that's considered an "optimisation" is debatable, but it would certainly be a neater solution

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56833/optimize-parsing-more-and-more-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing more you can optimize there. And I doubt that **THIS** is the slowest place in your program.

However your null-values are a bit odd. -999 for numbers? `DateTime.Now` for a DateTime? Are you sure that won't cause problems in other code? Those are pretty normal values which means that other code won't be able to distinguish whether you had a null, or an actual value. And this default value might be wrong for the other code.

If it was me, I'd use 0 for integer, and `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`. Or better yet - just stick to nullables all the way.

Comment: Even 0 for int isn't great, I think having a Nullable<int> would be best

Comment: @James - I know, but if you absolutely MUST have non-nullable numbers, then better stick to what the .NET considers "default" values. Otherwise you'll just confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

"== false" is not very readable. Use ! instead.

If the "object value" is already of desired type (e.g. DateTime), it would be slower to convert it to string and then back again.

I would write instead

```
if (value is DateTime) return (DateTime)value;
```

I would not use var result = -999; as a return value.

If the conversion fails, you can either return Int32.MinValue (better than -999) or rather null.

Maybe also you would like to check for DBNull.Value? So first I would check for null and DBNull.Value, then "value is DateTime" check and the last thing would be DateTime.TryParse.